# How to install pip and other specific python modules onto a CentOS server that is air-gapped from the internet?

Tags: centos6, yum, pip, saltstack

Ultimately, I'm trying to install SaltStack on a super computer that has no internet connection.  And I'm not allowed to hook it to the internet.  So far, I have installed an entire yum repo on the server and a CPAN.

But the yum repo can't find SaltStack (I don't know why, but I do plan on doing another rsync of my yum repo tonight and updating it on the server...that said, this repo is only 3 months old), so I resorted to trying to install pip on this server, but yum also can't find pip or python-pip.  So now, I have to figure out how to get pip installed from source on there and if there's a general, large dir of python modules I can rsync and just throw on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

salt-stack is in the epel repo. You will need to rsync from the epel repo [here](http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/EPEL/). I assume that you know that you need to run createrepo after the rsync.

Comment: I'm still a bit fuzzy on what role the createrepo does.  I set up a yum repo on my server and adjusted config files.  I was able to install a few things, but granted not everything I was expecting though...I've read a few tutorials using createrepo...they all seem a bit different, so I was confused as to which one to go with....  Thanks for the epel info though. I'll try it out today.

Comment: http://someideas.net/redhat/centos/setup-local-repository-centos-64 looks like a good place to start. The point of createrepo is to create a sqlite db that indexes what is in the repo to enable faster searching. Every time you update the files in a repo you need to run createrepo to re-create the sqlite table and thus the indexes (because you might have gotten new files).

Comment: Thank you both.  Not sure why I got downvoted for my question.  I will go back and make sure that I'm running createrepo.  I had read another tutorial that showed me the rsync and then some config file changes, I believe, and I got it going that way.  But it sounds like it isn't the best approach.